Connecting SQL Anywhere 11 to Python
I want to connect my SQL Anywhere to Python using Python module in this sqlanydb repository. When I try the repository on  my Python 3.9. With this code according to repository,
import sqlanydb
conn = sqlanydb.connect(uid='dba', pwd='sql', eng='demo', dbn='demo' )
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select 'Hello, world!'")
print( "SQL Anywhere says: %s" % curs.fetchone() )
curs.close()
conn.close()

It show this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\bantu\test_sqlany.py", line 2, in <module>
  conn = sqlanydb.connect(uid='dba', pwd='sql', eng='sddb', dbn='sddb' )
File "C:\Users\siaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
  packages\sqlanydb.py", line 566, in connect
  return Connection(args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\siaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
 packages\sqlanydb.py", line 582, in __init__
 parent = Connection.cls_parent = Root("PYTHON")
File "C:\Users\siaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
 packages\sqlanydb.py", line 496, in __init__
 self.api = load_library(os.getenv( 'SQLANY_API_DLL', None ), 'dbcapi.dll', 
 'libdbcapi_r.so',
File "C:\Users\siaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
 packages\sqlanydb.py", line 475, in load_library
 raise InterfaceError("Could not find dbcapi.dll.  Please append the directory that 
 contains dbcapi.dll to PYTHONPATH")
 sqlanydb.InterfaceError: ('Could not find dbcapi.dll.  Please append the directory 
that contains dbcapi.dll to PYTHONPATH', 0)

How to solve it?
